# Position of element in an array

Tags: ruby

I want to find the position of element in an array.

**Example:**

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I want to get the position of "**c**" as "**3**"

I tried as `arr.index("c") + 1`. Is there any other way where we can get the position directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use another way?

Comment: What's wrong with `index`?

Comment: I want to find the position of the elements and I don't prefer incrementing with the index.

Comment: You don't increment the index, you just calculate the index for the case when the first element would have index 1 instead of 0. Zero-based indexing is pretty common in programming languages, though.

Comment: Why dont you add a method to `Array` that returns index + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Ruby` by default index start with `0` but you can set position directly:

```
=> arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
#> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
=> arr.map.with_index(1) { |i, x| p "index #{x} - elem #{i}" }
#> "index 1 - elem a"
#> "index 2 - elem b"
#> "index 3 - elem c"
#> "index 4 - elem d"
=> ["index 1 - elem a", "index 2 - elem b", "index 3 - elem c", "index 4 - elem d"]
```